# PHP: How to pass variable from regular expression replacement to a function?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that takes

```
[QUOTE=3]
```

and transforms it into

```
<div class="quoted"><div class="quotation-author">Originally written by <strong>AUTHOR_WITH_ID=3</strong></div>
```

I got it almost right, but I'm unable to pass a variable to a function that gets author name.

```
$comment = preg_replace('/\[\s*QUOTE=(\d+)\s*\]/i', '<div class="quoted"><div class="quotation-author">Originally written by <strong>'.get_comment_author((int)'$1').'</strong></div>', $comment);
```

Comment: Should '$1' be single quoted?

Comment: @MyStream: Yes, we want the literal string `'$1'`.

Comment: isn't second argument of preg_replace casted to string *before* the replacement is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement:

```
'<div class="quoted"><div class="quotation-author">Originally written by <strong>'.get_comment_author((int)'$1').'</strong></div>'
```

does not happen dynamically; it is evaluated, then passed as an argument. Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to call a function for each match as follows:

```
$comment = preg_replace_callback('/\[\s*QUOTE=(\d+)\s*\]/i', function($m) {
    return '<div class="quoted"><div class="quotation-author">Originally written by <strong>'.get_comment_author((int) $m[1]).'</strong></div>';
}, $comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `preg_replace` for this, as the call to `get_comment_author` (and the `(int)` cast) happens *before* `preg_replace` is ran.

Try using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$comment = preg_replace_callback('/\[\s*QUOTE=(\d+)\s*\]/i', function($a){
    return '<div class="quoted"><div class="quotation-author">Originally written by <strong>'.get_comment_author($a[1]).'</strong></div>';
}, $comment);
```

Note: Depending on what `get_comment_author` does, you shouldn't need the `(int)` cast.